# I am trying to get the date a user was last online and which game he played last. However I get a not a single-group group function error

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is as follows

```
SELECT 
    GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERID, GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERNAAM,
    LAATSTONLINE,GAME.GAMENAAM,
    MAX(ITEMS_IN_BEZIT.LAATSTGEBRUIKT) AS "Laatst gespeelde game"
FROM 
    GEBRUIKERS
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ITEMS_IN_BEZIT ON GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERID = ITEMS_IN_BEZIT.GEBRUIKERID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    GAME ON ITEMS_IN_BEZIT.ITEMID = GAME.ITEMID
ORDER BY 
    GAME.GAMENAAM
```

This query should give me the user name the user id when he was last online and which game he played last

However I get the error as mentioned in the title.

Now my question: is there either a better way to formulate my query or is there a way to get arround this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `GROUP BY` when using aggregation functions:

```
SELECT GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERID, 
       GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERNAAM, 
       LAATSTONLINE, 
       GAME.GAMENAAM, 
       MAX(ITEMS_IN_BEZIT.LAATSTGEBRUIKT) AS "Laatst gespeelde game" 
FROM   GEBRUIKERS 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEMS_IN_BEZIT 
                    ON GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERID = ITEMS_IN_BEZIT.GEBRUIKERID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN GAME 
                    ON ITEMS_IN_BEZIT.ITEMID = GAME.ITEMID 
GROUP  BY GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERID,   -- here
          GEBRUIKERS.GEBRUIKERNAAM, 
          LAATSTONLINE,             
          GAME.GAMENAAM             
ORDER  BY GAME.GAMENAAM
```